# NPE on SolverVariable in ConstraintLayout

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I've been encountering a weird issue when using ConstraintLayout. I use it with Data Binding.
The error seems to be happening when some data is null, but I haven't been able to pinpoint exact steps to reproduce.

The app doesn't crash, but I'd love to understand where the exception is coming from.

The stack trace is as below:

```
04-25 15:32:00.628 25541-25541/gg.matecrate.matecrate W/System.err: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 'android.support.constraint.solver.SolverVariable android.support.constraint.solver.widgets.ConstraintAnchor.mSolverVariable' on a null object reference
        at android.support.constraint.solver.widgets.Chain.applyChainConstraints(Chain.java:165)
        at android.support.constraint.solver.widgets.Chain.applyChainConstraints(Chain.java:63)
        at android.support.constraint.solver.widgets.ConstraintWidgetContainer.addChildrenToSolver(ConstraintWidgetContainer.java:197)
04-25 15:32:00.629 25541-25541/gg.matecrate.matecrate W/System.err:     at android.support.constraint.solver.widgets.ConstraintWidgetContainer.layout(ConstraintWidgetContainer.java:360)
        at android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout.solveLinearSystem(ConstraintLayout.java:1800)
        at android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout.onMeasure(ConstraintLayout.java:1562)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:22002)
        at android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout.internalMeasureChildren(ConstraintLayout.java:1210)
        at android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout.onMeasure(ConstraintLayout.java:1550)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:22002)
        at android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout.internalMeasureChildren(ConstraintLayout.java:1210)
04-25 15:32:00.630 25541-25541/gg.matecrate.matecrate W/System.err:     at android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout.onMeasure(ConstraintLayout.java:1550)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:22002)
        at android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView.measureChildWithMargins(NestedScrollView.java:1450)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
04-25 15:32:00.631 25541-25541/gg.matecrate.matecrate W/System.err:     at android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView.onMeasure(NestedScrollView.java:516)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:22002)
        at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1632)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:22002)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6580)
        at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasureChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:739)
        at android.support.design.widget.HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.onMeasureChild(HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.java:91)
        at android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior.onMeasureChild(AppBarLayout.java:1361)
        at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasure(CoordinatorLayout.java:809)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:22002)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6580)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
        at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:141)
04-25 15:32:00.632 25541-25541/gg.matecrate.matecrate W/System.err:     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:22002)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6580)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1514)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:806)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:685)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:22002)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6580)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:22002)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6580)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1514)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:806)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:685)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:22002)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6580)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onMeasure(DecorView.java:721)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:22002)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2410)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1498)
04-25 15:32:00.633 25541-25541/gg.matecrate.matecrate W/System.err:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1751)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1386)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6733)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:911)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:723)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:658)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:897)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
```

Comment: Can you post the code for the layout and how you are interacting with it on the `Activity`?

Answer (score 0):

Your ConstraintLayout may have a circular dependency. That's how I got this same exception in a layout that didn't contain any databinding. The cause turned out to be two components where two chains met, and each component's constraints referenced the other. Can't show too much code here because it's for work but here's the gist of it:

```
           <!-- some components chained layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf here -->
           <!-- this is the last element in the chain: -->
           <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/app_logo"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/hostNameField" />

           <!-- This is the first element in a new chain: -->
           <EditText
            android:id="@+id/hostNameField"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/app_logo" />
           <!-- more components chained layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf here -->
```

The constraint solver in ConstraintLayout version 1.0.2 was able to render this in a reasonable way - the NPE started when I upgraded to 1.1.0.

The fix was to merge the two chains. I started with the ImageView and replaced the `app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf` with a `app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf` referencing the item above it. Then I did the same thing to that item, working my way up the chain until I got to the top item and replaced its constraint with `app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"`.